# Every conformal vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homothetic?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, symmetry, conformal-geometry, homothety

Consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for $n \ge 3$). Is it true that every conformal vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homothetic?

A vector field is homothetic if its flow is a *homothety*- a conformal map with a **constant** conformal factor. Equivalently, $V \in \Gamma(T\mathbb{R}^n)$ is homothetic if and only if
$$ \lambda \cdot g(X,Y)=g(\nabla_X V,Y)+g(X,\nabla_Y V),$$

where $g$ is the Euclidean metric, and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

I know the Killing fields are exactly those of the form $$ X(x)=Ax+b, \, \text{ where } \, A \, \text{ is a skew symmetric matrix and } \, b \in \mathbb{R}^n.  $$

Is there an explicit description of the conformal algebra of $\mathbb{R}^n$? (somehow I am having trouble finding a reference).

I hope for an elementary argument. (I thought to use [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(conformal_mappings)) but this seems an overkill, and I am not sure my use is correct).

Comment: Formula (15) on page 110 in https://zr9558.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/lars-v-ahlfors-mc3b6bius-transformations-in-several-dimensions.pdf. These quadratic vector fields form the Lie algebra of $Conf(S^n)$. Ahlfors then gives a very simple proof that there are no other conformal vector fields on the sphere.

Comment: One more remark: Ahlfors' book is known to have some minor errors. One of them is that what he calls a **quasiconformal deformation** should not be required to be a homeomorphism (it is actually a quasiconformal vector field). His $0$-quasiconformal deformation is nothing but a conformal vector field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing an answer using Moishe Cohen's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626350/every-conformal-vector-field-on-mathbbrn-is-homothetic?noredirect=1#comment5423802_2626350):

Let $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and define $V:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ by
$$ V(x)=b|x|^2-2 \langle b,x \rangle x.$$

We shall show $V$ is a conformal vector field which is not a homothety. Since we are on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\nabla V=dV$ is the standard derivative.

$$ dV_x(y)=2\langle x,y \rangle b-2 \langle b,y \rangle x-2\langle b,x \rangle y$$

If we write $S(y)=\langle b,y \rangle x$, then $S^T(y)=\langle x,y \rangle b$, so

$$ (dV_x)^T(y)=2\langle b,y \rangle x-2 \langle x,y \rangle b-2\langle b,x \rangle y.$$

This implies

$$ dV_x(y)+(dV_x)^T(y)=-4\langle b,x \rangle y,$$ i.e.

$$ dV_x+(dV_x)^T=-4\langle b,x \rangle \text{Id}.$$

This implies $V$ is conformal, since the conformal equation is $$ \nabla V+(\nabla V)^T=h\text{Id}_{TM},$$

where $h \in C^{\infty}(M)$.

(By taking traces of both sides, one sees that $h=\frac{2}{n} \text{tr}(\nabla V)=\frac{2}{n} \text{div} V$).

So here, $\text{div} V=-2n\langle b,x \rangle$ is not constant, so $V$ is not homothetic.